# Are $x_1=t\cos(t)$ and $x_2=t\sin(t)$ are solutions to the ODE $x''=q(t)x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, solution-verification

I have an ODE of the form $x''=q(t)x$ and need to determine if there exists any continuous $q(t)$ so that $x_1=t\cos(t)$ and $x_2=t\sin(t)$ are linear independednt solutions of this ODE in $(-\pi,\pi)$.

**My attempt** : I calculated $x_1''(t) = -2\sin(t) - t\cos(t)$ and $x_2''(t) = 2\cos(t) - t\sin(t)$, so once $q(t) = \frac{-2\sin(t) - t\cos(t)}{t\cos(t)}$ and in the second case $q(t) = \frac{2\cos(t) - t\sin(t)}{t\sin(t)}$. I don't see how this two can be the same, so my answer would be no. I wanted to check with you if that's correct.

Also what got me confused is that i read that linear combinations of solutions of ODE-s are also solutions, and I have proved that $x_1=\cos(t)$ and $x_2=\sin(t)$ are actually solutions of our ODE, so I don't know if that implies anything for our new possible solutions now.

Would be glad for some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
 x_1( \pi/2)  = 0 \, , \,  x_1''(\pi/2) \ne 0
$$
shows that $x_1$ is not the solution of an ODE $x''=q(t)x$ with a continuous function $q$ on $(-\pi, \pi)$.

A similar argument shows that $x_2$ is also not the solution of such an ODE.

If you restrict the domain to an interval where neither $x_1$ nor $x_2$ have zeros, for example $I= (0, \pi/2)$ then your approach still works and shows that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not both solutions on $I$:
$$
 q(t) = \frac{-2\sin(t) - t\cos(t)}{t\cos(t)} =  \frac{2\cos(t) - t\sin(t)}{t\sin(t)}
$$
leads to $- \sin^2(t) =  \cos^2(t)$  or $-\sin^2(t) = 1-\sin^2(t)$, which is impossible.

*Alternatively:* If two function $x_1$, $x_2$ are solutions of the same ODE $x'' = q(t) x$ on $I$ then
$$
 x_1'' x_2 - x_1 x_2'' = 0
$$
on $I$, and if $x_2 \ne 0$ then
$$
 x_2(t)^2 \frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{x_1(t)}{x_2(t)} \right) = \text{const}
$$
But in our case is
$$
x_2(t)^2 \frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{x_1(t)}{x_2(t)} \right) = t^2 \sin^2(t) \frac{d}{dt}\cot(t) = -t^2 \, .
$$

Comment: That’s true, but I guess OP’s solution works as well, and proves the claim even on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$?

Comment: @Milten: Yes, that would work as well. I just find this easier, and it shows a bit more, namely that none of the functions is a solution of such an ODE. $x_2$ fails at $t=0$.

Comment: I agree; I just mentioned it since I thought that both perspectives have value. I overlooked that $x_2$ fails at $t=0$, so I meant to say that OP showed that it couldn't even work on e.g. $(0,\pi/2)$ (where both $x_1$ and $x_2$ potentially work) or any other restricted interval.

Comment: @Milten: I was just about to add that argument ... thanks for your feedback!